# tabulator extra column gets added :-(

Tags: php, tabulator

```
var tabledata = [
    {givenToUser:"User1", groupName:"group1", userName:"user one"},
    {givenToUser:"User2", groupName:"group2", userName:"user two"},
];


//Build Tabulator

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    responsiveLayout:"collapse",
    responsiveLayoutCollapseStartOpen:false,
    columns:[
        {
            formatter:"responsiveCollapse", 
            width:30, 
            minWidth:30, 
            hozAlign:"center", 
            resizable:false, 
            headerSort:false
        },
        {
            title:"Group Name", 
            field:"groupName"
        },
        {
            title:"User's Reference", 
            field:"givenToUser", 
            responsive:0
        },
        {
            title:"User's Name", 
            field:"userName"
        },

    ],
});

</script>
```

It gets rendered well... using version  5.4.4

I have been cracking my brains on why this adds an extra column at the end!

What am i missing? probably something very mundane

Thanks

Comment: `why this adds an extra column at the end!` -> what extra columns getting added? could you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we cn check

Answer (score 0):

I've tried runnning your code and the problem can be resolved by changing the property `layout` to `"fitDataTable"`.

You can also try using other properties listed [here](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/layout#layout).